# Fetching labeled files into a TFSBuild

Tags: visual-studio, label, tfsbuild

I am sure there is a simple answer to this, but my google-fu fails me.

I have a team project in TFS 2008 that builds OK when using the latest code, however I now have a need to fetch the previous versions of a subset of the files at build time.  The subset of files are all labeled with the same label ("MyLabel" in the snippet below).

The snippet of XML I have added to be TFSBuild.proj file looks like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BuildLabel>LMyLabel</BuildLabel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="BeforeCompile">
    <Get
        TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
        BuildUri="$(BuildUri)"
        Condition=" '$(SkipGet)'!='true' "
        Workspace="$(WorkspaceName)"
        Recursive="$(RecursiveGet)"
        Force="$(ForceGet)"
        Version ="$(BuildLabel)" 
        Preview="false"
    />
  </Target>
```

This successfully fetches the subset of files into the source area, however it also deletes all other files in the source area.

i.e. the build process does the following:

1. fetch latest versions of all files into the source area
2. fetch labeled version of subset of files into the source area
3. delete all non-labeled files from the source area
4. run build

The build fails with the following error:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(997,5): error MSB3491: Could not write lines to file "[build directory]\Sources\MySolution.sln.x64.Release.vsprops". Could not find a part of the path '[build directory]\Sources\MySolution.x64.Release.vsprops'.

(which basically indicates that it can't find the solution, because it's been deleted)

I've tried adding the following snippet to the bottom of the XML:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SkipClean>true</SkipClean>
    <SkipInitializeWorkspace>true</SkipInitializeWorkspace>
    <ForceGet>false</ForceGet>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

but the result is the same.

So, my question is: how do I build my solution when it is a mixture of latest versions and older, labeled versions?  What am I missing?

(I realize I could just branch the baseline but for various reasons I would like to explore this approach first)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple approach that come to mind:

1. Get your latest version to workspace1
2. Get your labeled version to workspace2
3. XCopy workspace1 content over workspace2 as a post-get action

What do you think? Worth the try?

Comment: Yes, I guess that would work.  I had hoped there would be a nicer solution, however the lack of answers would seem to indicate otherwise.  In the end I went down the branch route, however I will bear this in mind for the future.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets, it appears that the version fetched for the build is controlled by the GetVersion property.  And that ForceGet is true by default.

I haven't tested it, but that implies to me that if you put

```
/property:GetVersion=*versionspec*
```

in the MSBuild Command Line Arguments textbox when you queue the build, it should fetch the specified version (look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56f7w6be%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for versionspec syntax.  If this fails for some reason, read Aaron Hallberg's [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaronhallberg/) until you understand msbuild better than I do:-)